# Set the password for the first build of openwrt

Tags: linux, root, openwrt

I want to build an openwrt source and set everything up through the menuconfig section
But there are no settings to set the password
Which part should I change or which section should I add?
I am creating openwrt for the tp-link archer modem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I've done this and was successful

The file `/etc/shadow` that the built firmware password setting is made in the operating system

The username and password of the operating system are displayed in an encrypted form in this file:

```
root:$1$/jQOKY73 $ pdcGJ7rwLtAjr67mpVFg2.:17759:0:99999:7:::
```

(this password is "admin")

You can first manually specify a password in an built operating system and then check this file

Next, copy the entire contents of this file and copy it to the Openwrt source in `/package/base-files/files/etc/shadow` (equivalent to the same file in the source).

And then build the operating system again

Comment: yes this solution is working . thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The password in OpenWRT is not **set**. The OpenWRT images have no root password  when they are deployed have no root password defined by default (at least for the TPLink Archer C2).

Only after deploying OpenWRT on the router, with Luci or in the Linux command line, you give it a root password.

See [OpenWRT- SSH Access for Newcomers](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-quick-start/sshadministration)